# Are the following proofs correct (1)?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

A list of some questions from class and my attempt at them are given below. Would appreciate any advice on what I did wrong or on how to attempt some of the questions.

> 1. Show that a linear operator maps zero to zero.

My attempt:

Let $T$ be a linear operator such that $T:X\to Y$ and $0_x \in X$ and $0_y \in  Y$ be the zero element of each space

Show $T(0_x) = y$, $y = 0_y$ and $y \in Y$

$$T(0_x)= T(0_x + 0_x) = T(0_x) + T(0_x) = y + y = y.$$

Thus $y = 0_y,$ as $y = y + y$ is only true for the zero element

> 2.Let $A: X \to Y$ be a linear operator from a linear space $X$ to a linear space $Y$.  Show
>   that the kernel of a linear operator $A: X \to Y$ is a linear subspace of $X$.

My attempt:

1. Showing non empty, $D : C ^∞ → C^∞$  , let D be the differential operator, then $\ker(D) = c$, $c \in F.$
2. Showing additive, where $x_1, x_2 \in \ker(X):$

> $Ax_1 = 0$ and $Ax_2 = 0$
>
> $A(x_1 + x_2) = 0$

3. Showing scalar multiplication for $a \in F:$

> $a(Ax_1)=a0$
>   $a0 = a0$

Comment: Please learn to use mathjax for readability. Click on my edit for an example how.

Comment: Thanks @spaceisdarkgreen will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Looks good to me. I'd maybe say one more sentence about how you know no nonzero vector satisfies $y+y=y$.

2.1. Why do you go to the differential operator here? You need to prove the kernel is always a linear subspace, not only in the case of the differential operator. In fact, why do you need to show at all that the kernel is nonempty?

2.2. Looks good. Perhaps note that what you did shows $x_1+x_2\in\ker A$.

2.3. I couldn't follow what you meant.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Y.Forman, for 2.1 I was told that to prove that something is a linear subspace is to show that it is non empty/that an example of it exists so I arbitrarily choose the differential operator example. In 2.3 I tried to show that the subspace is closed under scalar multiplication

Comment: @StackUser You're welcome! I'm still a confused what you mean by "nonempty." To say that the kernel of a linear operator is nonempty means that given an arbitrary linear operator (not a specific example!), there is at least one vector in its kernel. Once you show that the kernel is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, nonemptiness is guaranteed by problem 1, as Eric Towers pointed out, because the 0 vector is in the kernel. That's different from showing that an example of the kernel exists -- showing an example exists would be showing that the class of linear operators is nonempty.

Answer (score 0):

1:  Rather than the airy "as $y+y=y$ is only true for the zero element".  Just subtract $y$ from both sides to explicitly find $y$.

2.1: Why is there a differential operator here?  You have already shown in problem 1 that the kernel is nonempty.